# Murexide or eriochrome black T for EDTA titration with milk

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

Should I use Murexide or eriochrome black T for EDTA titration with milk? I am heating the milk to different temperatures and trying to find how the amount of calcium differs (or doesn't).

Comment: Read this article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022030261898548

Comment: Could you give a little background to this? Because obviously the calcium cannot evaporate, there must be another reason why the apparent content might change.

Comment: @Karl Calcium in milk is not free, but kept bound in phosphate groups of casseine, encapsulated in protein structure. That may compete with EDTA thermodynamically and kinetically. Additionally, there are protein changes with temperature change.

Comment: @Poutnik, This is exactly why pre-treatment of milk is necessary before titration. All info is given that official paper by the dairy association.  sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022030261898548

Comment: Yes, It was clear to me.. :-) But the efficiency of the pretreatment may be temperature dependent.